# Angle of projection for the minimum time of flight for a given range

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, gravity, kinematics, projectile

If a projectile has to cover a fixed range under gravity, then what should be the angle of projection for the total time of flight to be minimum?
The initial and final point of the projectile are both on level ground, gravity is constant, and the projectile is a point object.
The initial velocity of the projectile is u

Comment: Technically, *the* minimum time is $0$, regardless of ‘angle of projection’ (actually there *is no* projection if $v=0$ ; )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets look at the equations

$$x=v_{{0}}\cos \left( \varphi  \right) t\tag 1$$
$$y=v_{{0}}\sin \left( \varphi  \right) t-\frac 12\,g{t}^{2}\tag 2$$

solve those equations  with  $~x=L~$ and $~y=0~$ for $~v_0~,\varphi~$
you obtain:

$$\varphi_L=\arctan\left(\frac{g\,t_L^2}{2\,L}\right)$$
$$v_{0L}=\frac 12\frac{\sqrt{g^2\,t_L^4+4\,L^2}}{t_L}$$

hence:  the  angle of projection $ ~\varphi_L~$ and the start velocity $~v_{0L}~$ both are function of the time $~t_L~$ so I don't think there is unique solution for your question ?

Comment: I guess that the problem assumes that the initial velocity $v_0$ provided by the rifle is known, while $t_L$ is unknown. Solving the last equation you wrote for $t_L$, if a solution exists (i.e. if your shot is strong enough to reach target) you get 2 feasible values (the other two values are negative, so meaningless for the physical problem), and thus 2 angles. From the expression for $\phi$ as a function of $t_L$, you can see that the lower $t_L$ the lower the angle $\phi$.

Comment: As a limit case, think at a target right under your feet. You can shot the projectile in horizontal direction (or any negative angle) or in the vertical direction above your head to hit the target in the 2 different ways described by the two solutions of the mathematical problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to hit the final target? If so, and if your rifle is powerful enough to reach tour target, you usually get two solutions, for two different angles of incidence w.r.t. the horizontal ground (with the only exception of the target placed at the maximum range of the rifle where you get only one value of the angle).

Among these two solutions, you need to take the one with the smaller angle, an thus the maximum horizontal component of the velocity (constant throughout the motion of the projectile, if air drag is neglected), and thus the minimum time needed to cover the horizontal distance.

Comment: Yes, in the problem I referenced this to, I got the lowest value of theta to be tan inverse of 1/3.   Now I need to cover a range of 60m, and have no idea how to proceed without getting an obnoxious decimal value for theta.      Thanks anyway tho

Comment: I haven't done the computations, but what @Eli has done looks ok to me. If you get these equations and put the data of your problem inside, you should get the right result

Comment: Yeah it looks like you might be right. Thanks a lot. I love this forum

Comment: i agree, it's cool. if the question is solved, please accept the answer, mine or Eli's really doesn't care, even if a better edited answer putting the two together should be the best choice